# how is docker-compose better than normal docker?

Tags: django, docker-compose

i'm currently using normal docker in my django-react application and have been asked to switch to docker compose. Please tell me how is it better than normal docker for testing and production.

Comment: Please do your own research. [so] is for help with existing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker-compose is here to easily create and maintain stack of containers/services.

All your stack is defined in an formatted yaml file who can looks like that:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

Here with on yaml file I've declared a mysql service and a wordpress service. It's easier than doing "docker run", "--link", etc...

Comment: Thanks mate! It was helpful. :)